# Trying to understand the logic of code:

Tags: java

I am trying to follow a tutorial [here](http://www.edu4java.com/en/game/game3.html).

I have a stripped down version of the function `moveBall()` which is:

> ```
> if (x + xa > getWidth() - 30) {
>   xa = -1;
>   y = y + 10;
> }
> if (x + xa < 0) {
>   xa = 1;
> }
> x = x + xa;
> ```

Ideally after touching the boundaries of the screen the ball should reverse its direction, which is true and it does happen. But if I put `System.out.println("in if")` inside any of the `if` conditions, it gets called each time before even the ball touches the boundary, the value for `xa` ideally should be set only once upon touching the boundary, or am I wrong? I am not probably getting the complete logic, can anyone please help?

the main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mini Tennis");
        FirstClass Fr = new FirstClass(); 
        frame.add(Fr);


        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        while(true){
            Fr.moveBall(); // executes the last
            Fr.repaint();  //executes first
            Thread.sleep(10); //executes second
        }



    }
```

Comment: Did you try to add *different* debug output in the *different* `if` clauses?

Comment: Yes but it just confuses me more, partly due to the operation being carried out quickly.

Comment: Off topic but I would kill the guy who wrote that code...

Comment: Thank goodness I did not :D

Comment: @user2822178 Did you try to use a debugger on this code? Step through it and try to understand what happens.

Comment: Okay let me try that!

Comment: @AdrianMitev can you suggest me a better tutorial to start with Java gaming?

Comment: It's not about gaming, it's about writing readable code.

Comment: If you want to call the if statement only once, the equation would be == instead of < or > than a certain amount. Well, you cannot assume that equal to is ever true if you have multiple moving objects. For example the ball moves horizontal and we have a wall that also moves in horizontal direction. In that case it could be that (depending on which object moves first) a collision is not measured. It is very common in collision detection world to have an object actually cross the 'collision value' and then be put back. You'll notice this in some games when bumping into the wall.

Comment: I wonder what the initial value of variable x is, whether it is initialised to zero just like the tutorial code or not.

Comment: Yes everything is according to the tutorial, I just put breakpoints and realized that the if condition is only executed when the ball touches the boundary. Secondly, in the while condition the first statement to execute is `Fr.repaint();` and not the first statement then `thread.sleep(10);` However then the loop gets back to the first statement which is `Fr.moveBall();` ideally this should be executed in order.

Comment: @Bram, your idea helpful as it might be but using < and > is the only way to call the succeeding statements once till the other is met. Once `x+xa > getWidth-30` is true, the variable xa is set to -1 hence future iterations will be negative unless the other if condition becomes true which will result in an increment to x. Hence the next if will be called only when `x+xa < 0`, that is when the other side of the boundary is reached. I have been debugging this whole day now, it has immensely helped me to understand how the above code works.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Lutz Horn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1907906/lutz-horn), after debugging the whole day, I guess I have understood what is happening in the above snippet, I will try my best to explain:

In the above stripped down version, the program starts with two variables:

int x = 0; 
int xa =1;

in the move function, collision with any boundary of the frame is detected, but in the above code I was interested in only the x plane.

The function is:

```
void move() {
        System.out.println("x + xa is: "+(x+xa));
        System.out.println("Game Width: "+(game.getWidth() - 30));
        if (x + xa < 0)
            xa = 1;
        if (x + xa > game.getWidth() - 30)
            xa = -1;
        x = x + xa;

    }
```

So x starts as 0, and xa which is equal to 1 gets added up, so x is 1 and the ball moves to the right, repaint is called and the above happenes over and over again. Then at one instance x becomes 269 (Debug message: getWIdth()-30 = 268 ). Now the body of the second if condition is executed:

```
if (x + xa > game.getWidth() - 30) // holds true when x+xa = 269
                xa = -1; // Hence setting the variable xa to -1
```

The above continues till x becomes less than 0 ( because -1 is being added up to 269 due to the above) Also worthy of note here is that subtracting 1 from x each time paint is called means the if condition will not get called repeatedly.

now when x becomes -1 we have the following resulting to true:

```
 if (x + xa < 0)
            xa = 1;
```

Hence again incrementing x till 269 and the process continues.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it is called is because the method you described is constantly running. It is constantly checking to see if it is inside the designated boundary line, this is the reason that the println is constantly called, because the function is designed to always be called and in this way it is always checking if it is out of bounds.

Think of it this way.. the method is always asking "am I out of bounds?" "am I out of bounds?" and once it is, it sets itself in reverse.

You assumed that the code would only run when it touches the boundary, but this is false. It will keep checking if it has touched the boundary even when it isn't touching it... this is the only way that the computer will know when the boundary has been reached and reverse it self (or whatever the code instructs it to do).

You also mentioned in the comments `why is the System.out.println` run when the  if block condition is not met`. This is because Java allows loops without braces around the body.

while (condition) 
    statement1; 
    statement2; //only first statement is in body of loop

Students assume body statements are in the body. Similarly,

while (condition) 
    statement1; statement2

Both statements appear to be in loop, but only first is. 
The above examples would not compile in other languages.

Comment: Yes but calling the method does not mean going inside the if block, unless and until the boundary is touched. Might be I am wrong because I am confused with this snippet.

Comment: Ahh. I see. I will edit my answer. Please read it in a minute.

Comment: Yes it does, however the code works as expected. If condition at the wall!

Answer (score 0):

When the ball touches the boundries `x + xa == getWidth() - 30` . At this time, the xa is not changed and the ball moves on

But the step after that `x + xa > getWidth() - 30` get ture and the xa is set to -1(which means heading for the reverse x direction)

Comment: True I understand that part, ideally after this if, it should not enter the if condition till it touches the wall again.

Comment: @user2822178 which if do you mean? And I suggest to edit the question: the y is not changed after  `if(x + xa > getWidth() - 30)`

Comment: Any one of the two, however putting breakpoints and debugging has helped me more and I realize that it works as intended. The if is called only when the ball touches the boundary.

Comment: @user2822178 good , it's always good to debug yourself first and try to understand the reason:)

Comment: Yes the wrong I did was to use debug statements and not breakpoints! Now I get its all clear however there is more mess to be understood the way while is executed.

Comment: @user2822178 [Debugging with Eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)